# Apache Lucene IndexFormatTooOldException

Tags: java, lucene

I'm using Apache Lucene 5.0.0 and I have the problem that after some time/some "transactions" the index seems to become corrupt and I get the following exception:

```
org.apache.lucene.index.IndexFormatTooOldException: Format version is not supported (resource BufferedChecksumIndexInput(NIOFSIndexInput(path="/opt/xyz/index/1/index/segments_5b"))): -911482135 (needs to be between 1071082519 and 1071082519). This version of Lucene only supports indexes created with release 4.0 and later.
    at org.apache.lucene.index.SegmentInfos.readCommit(SegmentInfos.java:288) ~[lucene-core-5.0.0.jar:5.0.0 1659987 - anshumgupta - 2015-02-15 12:20:03]
    at org.apache.lucene.index.StandardDirectoryReader$1.doBody(StandardDirectoryReader.java:53) ~[lucene-core-5.0.0.jar:5.0.0 1659987 - anshumgupta - 2015-02-15 12:20:03]
    at org.apache.lucene.index.StandardDirectoryReader$1.doBody(StandardDirectoryReader.java:50) ~[lucene-core-5.0.0.jar:5.0.0 1659987 - anshumgupta - 2015-02-15 12:20:03]
    at org.apache.lucene.index.SegmentInfos$FindSegmentsFile.run(SegmentInfos.java:642) ~[lucene-core-5.0.0.jar:5.0.0 1659987 - anshumgupta - 2015-02-15 12:20:03]
    at org.apache.lucene.index.StandardDirectoryReader.open(StandardDirectoryReader.java:50) ~[lucene-core-5.0.0.jar:5.0.0 1659987 - anshumgupta - 2015-02-15 12:20:03]
    at org.apache.lucene.index.DirectoryReader.open(DirectoryReader.java:63) ~[lucene-core-5.0.0.jar:5.0.0 1659987 - anshumgupta - 2015-02-15 12:20:03]
```

Here the pieces of code that I use to perform the search and indexing operations:

**Search**:

```
Directory directory = getIndexDirectory();
IndexReader indexReader = DirectoryReader.open(directory);
IndexSearcher is = new IndexSearcher(indexReader);
...


private Directory getDirectory() throws Exception {
    final File dir = new File(...);
    return FSDirectory.open(dir.toPath());
}
```

And for **indexing** I get the index writer with the following method, passing as parameter the same directory:

```
private IndexWriter getIndexWriter(final Directory directory) throws Exception {
    return new IndexWriter(directory, getIndexWriterConfig());
}

private IndexWriterConfig getIndexWriterConfig() {
    final IndexWriterConfig config = new IndexWriterConfig(new StandardAnalyzer());
    config.setOpenMode(OpenMode.CREATE_OR_APPEND);
    return config;
}
```

When I create the index from scratch and perform a re-indexing of all documents the search works fine. I can add new documents to the index and/or remove existing ones and the search continues to work. However after a while (I cannot understand the "trigger" of the problem) the search stops to work and I get this IndexFormatTooOldException.

Do you have an idea what could be the cause of this problem?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Problem fixed: was caused by a second instance of the application (run inside Jenkins tests) accessing the same index...